# Calculate cosine similarity given 2 sentence strings

Tags: python, string, nlp, similarity, cosine-similarity

From [Python: tf-idf-cosine: to find document similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118720/python-tf-idf-cosine-to-find-document-similarity) , it is possible to calculate document similarity using tf-idf cosine. Without importing external libraries, are that any ways to calculate cosine similarity between 2 strings?

```
s1 = "This is a foo bar sentence ."
s2 = "This sentence is similar to a foo bar sentence ."
s3 = "What is this string ? Totally not related to the other two lines ."

cosine_sim(s1, s2) # Should give high cosine similarity
cosine_sim(s1, s3) # Shouldn't give high cosine similarity value
cosine_sim(s2, s3) # Shouldn't give high cosine similarity value
```

Comment: I don't have the answer, but something like word2vec (https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/) would probably be a good start if you want meaningful results.

Comment: @static_rtti word2vec has got nothing to do with cosine similarity. Thats about embeddings. Here he is giving the two strings from which he wants to calculate cosine similarity.

Comment: If anyone is looking for **semantic similarity**, [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html) can be helpful.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/71822208/610569

Answer (score 187, accepted):

A simple pure-Python implementation would be:

```
import math
import re
from collections import Counter

WORD = re.compile(r"\w+")


def get_cosine(vec1, vec2):
    intersection = set(vec1.keys()) & set(vec2.keys())
    numerator = sum([vec1[x] * vec2[x] for x in intersection])

    sum1 = sum([vec1[x] ** 2 for x in list(vec1.keys())])
    sum2 = sum([vec2[x] ** 2 for x in list(vec2.keys())])
    denominator = math.sqrt(sum1) * math.sqrt(sum2)

    if not denominator:
        return 0.0
    else:
        return float(numerator) / denominator


def text_to_vector(text):
    words = WORD.findall(text)
    return Counter(words)


text1 = "This is a foo bar sentence ."
text2 = "This sentence is similar to a foo bar sentence ."

vector1 = text_to_vector(text1)
vector2 = text_to_vector(text2)

cosine = get_cosine(vector1, vector2)

print("Cosine:", cosine)
```

Prints:

```
Cosine: 0.861640436855
```

The cosine formula used here is described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity).

This does not include weighting of the words by tf-idf, but in order to use tf-idf, you need to have a reasonably large corpus from which to estimate tfidf weights.

You can also develop it further, by using a more sophisticated way to extract words from a piece of text, stem or lemmatise it, etc.

Comment: How about "Felines feed on mice" and "Rodents are often eaten by cats"? You code incorrectly returns 0.

Comment: Surely, an SO question is not the place to definitively solve the problem of modelling semantic similarity of sentences. The question is about measuring (surface) similarity between two bits of text, that's what the code does.

Comment: The code returns 0, correctly, because it measures surface similarity of two texts, it does not measure meaning as such.

Comment: I agree with your first point and disagree with the second. SO is not for long and theoretical scientific discussions, which is why I refrained from talking about the technical side. While your answer is to the point and correct, the question is clearly *not* about surface similarity. Please have another look at the example sentences in the question.

Comment: I think @vpekar's approach is more like a basic lesk where the surface words are considered as without semantic knowledge.

Comment: @2er0 Did you mean to ask about how to use external semantic knowledge when measuring similarity between two sentences?

Comment: not really but just a generic question on whether `cosine similarity` can be achieved without external library.

But it's good to note @mbatchkarov's advice on more realistic setup for cosine similarity.

Comment: You asked specifically about cosine. I answered specifically that question. The cosine is implemented as "realistically" as you can possibly get. If you mean to say, "how to do better than cosine to measure similarity", then it's a different question.

Comment: @vpekar Does calculating cosine similarity require that both vectors' dimension should be the same?
Can you really calculate the cosine of (0,1) and (0,1,0)? Also, this similarity score doesn't catch the differences of word sequence. If text1='This is a foo bar sentence .' and text2 = 'is This a foo bar sentence .', the cosine score is 1.

Comment: The cosine similarity assumes that if a target word did not co-occur with a context word, then the corresponding value in the feature vector is 0. So the implementation above does not compare vectors of different dimensions. Re. 2nd question - yes, the cosine ignores the sequence of words in the sentence.

Answer (score 53):

The short answer is "no, it is not possible to do that in a principled way that works even remotely well". It is an unsolved problem in natural language processing research and also happens to be the subject of my doctoral work. I'll very briefly summarize where we are and point you to a few publications:

**Meaning of words**

The most important assumption here is that it is possible to obtain a vector that represents each *word* in the sentence in quesion. This vector is usually chosen to capture the contexts the word can appear in. For example, if we only consider the three contexts "eat", "red" and "fluffy", the word "cat" might be represented as [98, 1, 87], because if you were to read a very very long piece of text (a few billion words is not uncommon by today's standard), the word "cat" would appear very often in the context of "fluffy" and "eat", but not that often in the context of "red". In the same way, "dog" might be represented as [87,2,34] and "umbrella" might be [1,13,0]. Imagening these vectors as points in 3D space, "cat" is clearly closer to "dog" than it is to "umbrella", therefore "cat" also means something more similar to "dog" than to an "umbrella".

This line of work has been investigated since the early 90s (e.g. [this](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Explorations_in_Automatic_Thesaurus_Disc.html?id=ZAxgQRIgzIcC&redir_esc=y) work by Greffenstette) and has yielded some surprisingly good results. For example, here is a few random entries in a thesaurus I built recently by having my computer read wikipedia:

```
theory -> analysis, concept, approach, idea, method
voice -> vocal, tone, sound, melody, singing
james -> william, john, thomas, robert, george, charles
```

These lists of similar words were obtained entirely without human intervention- you feed text in and come back a few hours later.

**The problem with phrases**

You might ask why we are not doing the same thing for longer phrases, such as "ginger foxes love fruit". It's because we do not have enough text. In order for us to *reliably* establish what X is similar to, we need to see many examples of X being used in context. When X is a single word like "voice", this is not too hard. However, as X gets longer, the chances of finding natural occurrences of X get exponentially slower. For comparison, Google has about 1B pages containing the word "fox" and not a single page containing "ginger foxes love fruit", despite the fact that it is a perfectly valid English sentence and we all understand what it means.

**Composition**

To tackle the problem of data sparsity, we want to perform composition, i.e. to take vectors for words, which are easy to obtain from real text, and to put the together in a way that captures their meaning. The bad news is nobody has been able to do that well so far.

The simplest and most obvious way is to add or multiply the individual word vectors together. This leads to undesirable side effect that "cats chase dogs" and "dogs chase cats" would mean the same to your system. Also, if you are multiplying, you have to be extra careful or every sentences will end up represented by [0,0,0,...,0], which defeats the point.

**Further reading**

I will not discuss the more sophisticated methods for composition that have been proposed so far. I suggest you read Katrin Erk's ["Vector space models of word meaning and phrase meaning: a survey"](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/lnco.362/abstract). This is a very good high-level survey to get you started. Unfortunately, is not freely available on the publisher's website, email the author directly to get a copy. In that paper you will find references to many more concrete methods. The more comprehensible ones are by [Mitchel and Lapata (2008)](http://aclweb.org/anthology-new/P/P08/P08-1028.pdf) and [Baroni and Zamparelli (2010)](http://clic.cimec.unitn.it/marco/publications/bz-adj-com-emnlp10.pdf).

---

Edit after comment by @vpekar:
The bottom line of this answer is to stress the fact that while *naive methods do exist* (e.g. addition, multiplication, surface similarity, etc), these are *fundamentally flawed* and in general one should not expect great performance from them.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what approach did you use to build the thesaurus?

Comment: It's a distributional thesaurus, built with [Byblo](https://github.com/MLCL/Byblo). In this particular instantiation each token has as features the other tokens that occurs in window of 5 words around it in all of Wikipedia, and similarity is calculated based on these features. We've built other thesauri where the features are the other words the target word has grammatical relations with. This generally works better, but requires at least a partial parse of the corpus, which takes a long time.

Comment: Why cannot we use RNN to handle composition? This way we'd take into account words order as well as their individual meaning.

Comment: Sure, you can. This answer is now over 5 years old. At the time RNNs were just starting to get big (again) and weren't really on my radar

Comment: @OlegAfanasyev - You mean to say AutoEncoder with CNN or RNNs? I am going to implement, could you provide any guidance if anything is required from as usual?

Comment: The last 2 paper links are now dead

Comment: Google has about 1B pages containing the word "fox" and not a single page containing "ginger foxes love fruit" -- now it does :D

Answer (score 8):

I have similar solution but might be useful for pandas

```
import math
import re
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

WORD = re.compile(r"\w+")


def get_cosine(vec1, vec2):
    intersection = set(vec1.keys()) & set(vec2.keys())
    numerator = sum([vec1[x] * vec2[x] for x in intersection])

    sum1 = sum([vec1[x] ** 2 for x in list(vec1.keys())])
    sum2 = sum([vec2[x] ** 2 for x in list(vec2.keys())])
    denominator = math.sqrt(sum1) * math.sqrt(sum2)

    if not denominator:
        return 0.0
    else:
        return float(numerator) / denominator


def text_to_vector(text):
    words = WORD.findall(text)
    return Counter(words)

df=pd.read_csv('/content/drive/article.csv')
df['vector1']=df['headline'].apply(lambda x: text_to_vector(x)) 
df['vector2']=df['snippet'].apply(lambda x: text_to_vector(x)) 
df['simscore']=df.apply(lambda x: get_cosine(x['vector1'],x['vector2']),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Download the file 'numberbatch-en-17.06.txt' from https://conceptnet.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/2017/numberbatch/numberbatch-en-17.06.txt.gz and extract it. The function 'get_sentence_vector' uses a simple sum of word vectors. However it can be improved by using weighted sum where weights are proportional to Tf-Idf of each word.

```
import math
import numpy as np

std_embeddings_index = {}
with open('path/to/numberbatch-en-17.06.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        values = line.split(' ')
        word = values[0]
        embedding = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
        std_embeddings_index[word] = embedding

def cosineValue(v1,v2):
    "compute cosine similarity of v1 to v2: (v1 dot v2)/{||v1||*||v2||)"
    sumxx, sumxy, sumyy = 0, 0, 0
    for i in range(len(v1)):
        x = v1[i]; y = v2[i]
        sumxx += x*x
        sumyy += y*y
        sumxy += x*y
    return sumxy/math.sqrt(sumxx*sumyy)


def get_sentence_vector(sentence, std_embeddings_index = std_embeddings_index ):
    sent_vector = 0
    for word in sentence.lower().split():
        if word not in std_embeddings_index :
            word_vector = np.array(np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, 300))
            std_embeddings_index[word] = word_vector
        else:
            word_vector = std_embeddings_index[word]
        sent_vector = sent_vector + word_vector

    return sent_vector

def cosine_sim(sent1, sent2):
    return cosineValue(get_sentence_vector(sent1), get_sentence_vector(sent2))
```

I did run for the given sentences and found the following results

```
s1 = "This is a foo bar sentence ."
s2 = "This sentence is similar to a foo bar sentence ."
s3 = "What is this string ? Totally not related to the other two lines ."

print cosine_sim(s1, s2) # Should give high cosine similarity
print cosine_sim(s1, s3) # Shouldn't give high cosine similarity value
print cosine_sim(s2, s3) # Shouldn't give high cosine similarity value

0.9851735249068168
0.6570885718962608
0.6589335425458225
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest answer I can come up with includes CounterVectorizer.

Suppose we have 3 pieces of text.

```
text_1 = """ """

text_2 = """ """

text_3 = """ """

documents = [text_1, text_2, text_3]
```

2. To compute cosine similarity, we need the count matrix of words from each document

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the Document Term Matrix
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
sparse_matrix = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)

# OPTIONAL: Convert Sparse Matrix to Pandas Dataframe if you want to see the word frequencies.
doc_term_matrix = sparse_matrix.todense()
df = pd.DataFrame(doc_term_matrix, 
                  columns=count_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), 
                  index=['text_1', 'text_2', 'text_3'])
df
```

3. And simply cosine similarity function does the job from sklearn.

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
print(cosine_similarity(df, df))
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you are aware of [word embeddings](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) like Glove/Word2Vec/Numberbatch, your job is half done. If not let me explain how this can be tackled. 
Convert each sentence into word tokens, and represent each of these tokens as vectors of high dimension (using the pre-trained word embeddings, or you could [train](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec) them yourself even!). So, now you just don't capture their surface similarity but rather extract the meaning of each word which comprise the sentence as a whole. After this calculate their cosine similarity and you are set.

Comment: What to do after getting each word embedding for sentence 1 (6 * 100) and sentence 2 (4*100) by assuming 6 word in first sentence & 100 is the embedding size and 4 word in second sentence with 100D is embedding. And can i do sum of word vector or guide me if you have any?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @vpekar for your implementation. It helped a lot. I just found that it misses the tf-idf weight while calculating the cosine similarity.
The Counter(word) returns a dictionary which has the list of words along with their occurence.

cos(q, d) = sim(q, d) = (q · d)/(|q||d|) = (sum(qi, di)/(sqrt(sum(qi2)))*(sqrt(sum(vi2))) where i = 1 to v)

- qi is the tf-idf weight of term i in the query.
- di is the tf-idf
- weight of term i in the document. |q| and |d| are the lengths of q
  and d.
- This is the cosine similarity of q and d . . . . . . or,
  equivalently, the cosine of the angle between q and d.

Please feel free to view my code [here](https://github.com/puneeth-u-bharadwaj/Data-Mining/blob/master/Cosine-Similarity/src/final/Puneeth_Umesh_Bharadwaj_PA1.py). But first you will have to download the anaconda package. It will automatically set you python path in Windows. Add this python interpreter in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Without using external libraries, you can try BLEU or its alternatives. You can refer to its standard implementation: [SACREBLEU](https://github.com/mjpost/sacrebleu).