# How to find similarity of sentence?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

How to find the semantic similarity between any two given sentences?

Eg:
what movies did ron howard direct?

movies directed by ron howard.

I know its a hard problem. But, would like to ask the views of experts.
I don't know how to use the Parts of Speech to achieve this.
http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp

Comment: Similar on what level?  "Movies not directed my Ron Howard" is lexically very similar to your second sentence but semantically its diametrical opposite.  Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: I don't see the purpose of your example. Are you working on a QA system? If yes you should state it, and make explicit what is your input and what is expected as output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate cosine similarity given 2 sentence strings? - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173225/how-to-calculate-cosine-similarity-given-2-sentence-strings-python)

Answer (score 0):

Its a broad problem. I would personally go for [cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity).

You need to convert your sentences into a vector. For converting the sentence into vector  you can consider several rules, like number of occurances, order, synonyms etc. Then taking the cosine distance as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173225/how-to-calculate-cosine-similarity-given-2-sentence-strings-python)

You can also explore elasticsearch for [finding associated words](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/shingles.html). You can create your custom analyzers, stemmer, tokenizer, filters(like synonyms) etc. which can be very helpful in finding similar sentences. Elasticsearch also provides [more like this query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) which finds similar documents using the tf-idf scores.