# Sorting string in order of high frequency terms from Inverted Index Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm new to Elasticsearch and I wanted to know if doing this was possible:

I have a bunch of Address strings that i want to sort on the most repetitive terms in the Strings.

For example:

```
1. Shop no 1 ABC Lane City1 - Zipcode1
2. Shop no 2 EFG Lane City1 - Zipcode2
3. Shop no 1 XYZ Lane City2 - Zipcode3
4. Shop no 3 ABC Lane City1 - Zipcode1
```

What i really need is to bunch them together on the most common terms in the strings.

So what the sorted output should be for the earlier example is:

```
    1. Shop no 1 ABC Lane City1 - Zipcode1 
    4. Shop no 3 ABC Lane City1 - Zipcode1 # Because 1 and 2 have the most common words in them.
    2. Shop no 2 EFG Lane City1 - Zipcode2 # Second most common words with 1 and 4.
    3. Shop no 1 XYZ Lane City2 - Zipcode3 # Not all that many common terms amongst them.
```

I have no idea about how to go about it.
I know i could fire each string as a query to get the results most close to the query being fired.
But i have a hundred thousand rows as such and it doesn't seem to be an efficient option at all.

If i could just `matchall()` and `sort` with a `term` filter with the most amount of recurring terms in every string, that would be really helpful.

Can there be a sort on the documents that contain most of the similar words in the inverted index?

Here's a sample pastebin of how my data looks:
[Sample Addresses](http://pastebin.com/hySkZ4Pn)

Comment: I don't know about elasticsearch, but python at least you can do a Counter of the words and then use build a key function with it to use with sort, say for example the sum of the count of every word in each term to sort

Comment: I've answered and showed how to use a simple (plain) python approach for this using cosine similarity. But, if you depend on issuing elastic search queries, you should possibly have a look at MLT queries (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

I have used https://stackoverflow.com/a/15174569/61903 to calculate the [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) of two strings (credits to @vpekar) as a base algorithm for similarity. Generally I put all the strings into a list. Then I set a index parameter i to 0 and loop over i as long as it is in the range of the list length. Within that loop I iterate a position p from i+1 to length(list). Then I find the maximum cosine value between list[i] and list[p]. Both textstrings will be put into a out list so they won't be taken into account in later similarity calculations. Both textstrings will be put into the result list along with the cosine value, the datastructure is VectorResult.

Afterwards the list is sorted by the cosine value. We now have unique string pairs with descending cosine, a.k.a. similarity value. HTH.

```
import re
import math
import timeit

from collections import Counter

WORD = re.compile(r'\w+')


def get_cosine(vec1, vec2):
    intersection = set(vec1.keys()) & set(vec2.keys())
    numerator = sum([vec1[x] * vec2[x] for x in intersection])

    sum1 = sum([vec1[x] ** 2 for x in vec1.keys()])
    sum2 = sum([vec2[x] ** 2 for x in vec2.keys()])
    denominator = math.sqrt(sum1) * math.sqrt(sum2)

    if not denominator:
        return 0.0
    else:
        return float(numerator) / denominator


def text_to_vector(text):
    words = WORD.findall(text)
    return Counter(words)


class VectorResult(object):
    def __init__(self, cosine, text_1, text_2):
        self.cosine = cosine
        self.text_1 = text_1
        self.text_2 = text_2

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.cosine == other.cosine:
            return True
        return False

    def __le__(self, other):
        if self.cosine <= other.cosine:
            return True
        return False

    def __ge__(self, other):
        if self.cosine >= other.cosine:
            return True
        return False

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.cosine < other.cosine:
            return True
        return False

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if self.cosine > other.cosine:
            return True
        return False

def main():
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    texts = []
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
        texts = f.readlines()

    cosmap = []
    i = 0
    out = []
    while i < len(texts):
        max_cosine = 0.0
        current = None
        for p in range(i + 1, len(texts)):
            if texts[i] in out or texts[p] in out:
                continue
            vector1 = text_to_vector(texts[i])
            vector2 = text_to_vector(texts[p])
            cosine = get_cosine(vector1, vector2)
            if cosine > max_cosine:
                current = VectorResult(cosine, texts[i], texts[p])
                max_cosine = cosine
        if current:
            out.extend([current.text_1, current.text_2])
            cosmap.append(current)
        i += 1

    cosmap = sorted(cosmap)

    for item in reversed(cosmap):
        print(item.cosine, item.text_1, item.text_2)

    end = timeit.default_timer()

    print("Similarity Sorting of {} strings lasted {} s.".format(len(texts), end - start))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Results**

I used your sampple adresses at http://pastebin.com/hySkZ4Pn as test data:

```
1.0000000000000002 NO 15& 16 1ST FLOOR,2ND MAIN ROAD,KHB COLONY,GANDINAGAR YELAHANKA
 NO 15& 16 1ST FLOOR,2ND MAIN ROAD,KHB COLONY,GANDINAGAR YELAHANKA

1.0 # 51/3 AGRAHARA YELAHANKA
 #51/3 AGRAHARA YELAHANKA

0.9999999999999999 # C M C ROAD,YALAHANKA
 # C M C ROAD,YALAHANKA

0.8728715609439696 # 1002/B B B ROAD,YELAHANKA
 0,B B ROAD,YELAHANKA

0.8432740427115678 # LAKSHMI COMPLEX C M C ROAD,YALAHANKA
 # SRI LAKSHMAN COMPLEX C M C ROAD,YALAHANKA

0.8333333333333335 # 85/1 B B M P OFFICE ROAD,KOGILU YELAHANKA
 #85/1 B B M P OFFICE NEAR KOGILU YALAHANKA

0.8249579113843053 # 689 3RD A CROSS SHESHADRIPURAM CALLEGE OPP YELAHANKA
 # 715 3RD CROSS A SECTUR SHESHADRIPURAM CALLEGE OPP YELAHANKA

0.8249579113843053 # 10 RAMAIAIA COMPLEX B B ROAD,YALAHANKA
 # JAMATI COMPLEX B B ROAD,YALAHANKA

[ SNIPPED ]

Similarity Sorting of 702 strings lasted 8.955146235887025 s.
```

Answer (score 1):

Cosine similarity is definitely the way to go.

Igor Motov created an Elasticsearch native script to compute this similarity value for a field across many documents.

[You can take a look here.](https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-native-script-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/examples/nativescript/script/CosineSimilarityScoreScript.java)

You would use this script inside [`script_score`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/script-score.html) or for [script-based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting).