# Python words phrase likeness degree comparison

Tags: python, scikit-learn, bigdata

Is there now a library/function for `Python` to compare word phrases and return degree of likeness and/or degree of how information in 1st phrase is fully present in 2nd phrase?

E.g. "Mr John Leron" compare to "Jonh Ler. Jr. teacher"?

I expect it could be some 'vector' function used in big data analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommand the cosine-similariy algorithm. The reference url is below.

[How to calculate cosine similarity given 2 sentence strings? - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173225/how-to-calculate-cosine-similarity-given-2-sentence-strings-python)