# Partial matching phrases in python

Tags: python, string-matching, sentence-similarity

I want to find partial matches between 2 strings/phrases and measure them on a scale of `[0,1]`. I tried using `SequenceMatcher` for the same.

Please find the sample code below:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

out1 = SequenceMatcher(lambda x:x == " ",'this is a private museum','temporary vice prez').ratio()
out2 = SequenceMatcher(lambda x:x == " ",'this is a private museum','museum').ratio()
```

Here, the score I get for `out1` is `0.279` and `out2` is `0.4`.
However, `out1` is not a match semantically, although `out2` makes sense. How to evaluate the strings at a word level ?

Expected output would be something like `out1 = 0` and `out2=0.4`. Scoring should be based on word-level similarity.

Any alternate solution would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Solved this using Cosine similarity as the measure by referring to the accepted solution by *vpekar* here:
[How to calculate cosine similarity given 2 sentence strings? - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173225/how-to-calculate-cosine-similarity-given-2-sentence-strings-python)

Comment: Well, both strings to compare start with a `t` and have `  pr` in them. Without doing the math I'd say that should give at least some point.

Comment: Agree with you @KlausD. But I'm looking for an alternate solution that'd match it at a word level.

Comment: What would be your expected output for such a case?

Comment: @NickilMaveli I've edited my question to add the expected output. I believe something on the lines of sentence similarity(taking into account word matching) would be useful.

Comment: I was able to achieve it using Cosine similarity. SO reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173225/how-to-calculate-cosine-similarity-given-2-sentence-strings-python

Comment: Good that you solved it using cosine similarity, you can have a look at Jaccard Index (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) too. It is pretty simple to implement and works many a times :)

Comment: @Yavar thanks for the suggestion! This works as well :)