# How to find a similar substring inside a large string with a similarity score in python?

Tags: python, string, nlp, distance, similarity

What I'm looking for is not just a plain similarity score between two texts. But a similarity score of a substring inside a string. Say:

```
text1 = 'cat is sleeping on the mat'.

text2 = 'The cat is sleeping on the red mat in the living room'.
```

In the above example, all the words of `text1` are present in the `text2` completely, hence the similarity should be 100%.

If some words of `text1` are missing, the score shall be less.

I'm working with a large dataset of varying paragraph size, hence finding a smaller paragraph inside a bigger one with such similarity score is crucial.

I found only string similarities such as cosine similarities, difflib similarity etc. which compares two strings. But not about a score of substring inside another string.

Comment: This question is about [tag:algorithms] rather than [tag:python].

Comment: This might be a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388213/find-the-similarity-percent-between-two-strings
But I would check out that library for comparing two strings. Then you will need to find a way to find the sub string.  It might work with sub strings.  Havent tested to try that out though.

Comment: Have you tried [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)? It may be useful here, included it in my answer as well.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173225/calculate-cosine-similarity-given-2-sentence-strings

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388213/find-the-similarity-percent-between-two-strings too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your description, how about:

```
>>> a = "cat is sleeping on the mat"
>>> b = "the cat is sleeping on the red mat in the living room"
>>> a = a.split(" ")
>>> score = 0.0
>>> for word in a: #for every word in your string
        if word in b: #if it is in your bigger string increase score
            score += 1
>>> score/len(a) #obtain percentage given total word number
1.0
```

In case it had a missing word for example:

```
>>> c = "the cat is not sleeping on the mat"
>>> c = c.split(" ")
>>> score = 0.0
>>> for w in c:
        if w in b:
            score +=1
>>> score/len(c)
0.875
```

Additionally, you can do as @roadrunner suggest and split `b` and save it as a set to speed up your performance with `b = set(b.split(" "))`. This will reduce that part complexity to `O(1)` and improve the overall algorithm to a `O(n)` complexity.

**Edit:** You say you already tried some metrics like Cosine Similarity etc. However I suspect you may benefit from checking the [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) similarity, which I suspect could be of some use in this case as addition to the solutions provided.

Comment: Nice answer, definitely the most simplest approach. I think you need to split `b` here though?

Comment: @RoadRunner thanks. This works without having to split `b` (pasted directly from my console). However, you *can* split it if you want the performance enhancement, which would be better I guess.

Comment: Yeah you're right. This gives the OP a good starting point, he/she can choose what to use and what not to use, depending on the text he/she is working with.

Comment: Thank you very much DarkCygnus and @RoadRunner. This and the above one, are a perfect fit for what I was looking for.  

I tried Levenshtein distance in my first attempt, but since my Text2 has unwanted text around it, I would get a lower similarity score when compared with Text1. Hence was looking for an alternative.

Comment: Clad I could help @SanjayKamath :) consider accepting an answer if it solved your problem once you've tried. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

You could also use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to store the counts of words in `word_a` that exist in `word_b`, then `sum()` the counts divided by the length of `word_a` at the end:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = "the cat is not sleeping on the mat"
b = "the cat is sleeping on the red mat in the living room"

word_a = a.split()
word_b = set(b.split())

d = defaultdict(int)
for word in word_a:
    if word in word_b:
        d[word] += 1

print(sum(d.values()) / len(word_a))
```

Which Outputs:

```
0.875
```

**Note:** Since we only care about checking if words in `word_a` exist in `word_b`, then converting `word_b` to a `set()` will allow `O(1)` lookup, instead of keeping it a list, which will be `O(n)`. This then makes the overall time complexity of the above code `O(n)`.

Comment: Interesting addition. So you say `word in word_b` is going to be O(1) if it is a set then? Still, you are doing `for word in word_a`, so that makes your algorithm O(n) right?

Comment: @DarkCygnus Yeah I agree, this solution is `O(n)`. I only added the set lookup optimization to slightly improve performance. I might have to run some tests on some bigger samples to see if it really makes much of a difference.

Comment: Indeed. OP can also tailor these options to fit his needs depending on the data he is handling. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Similar to DarkCygbus but the similarity is based on its count total character instead of words. On the other hand, this script has only checked coincidence with the complete words (text_2.split())

```
from __future__ import division

text_1 = 'cat is sleeping on the mat'
text_2 = 'The cat is sleeping on the red mat in the living room'
no_match = 0
match = 0

for word in text_1.split():
    if word not in text_2.split():
        no_match += len(word)
    else:
        match += len(word)

similarity = match/(match + no_match)
print ('{0:.0%}'.format(similarity))
```

Comment: Although this seems like an alternative approach, OP seems to clearly ask about some way of considering similarities between *words*, as he mentions it several times in the Question, i.e.: "But not about a score of substring inside another string.", "In the above example, the words...is present in the Text2 completely, hence the similarity should be 100%."

Comment: Besides, I suspect that your approach may give some unexpected behavior. If you compare *by characters* instead of by words, you may get 100% match in things like "**asdf**" and "**as** you **d**id **f**irst", as it contains all characters, even though they are completely different things.

Comment: I don't think so, if you check in your script 'a' like a = "cat is sleeping on the mat lee ivi"  .. its similarity will be 100%, in my script 81%.

Comment: Words like 'ivi' and 'lee' don't make sense and probably are not present on typed text analysis. Still, my last comment is true, but I agree that my approach may have different results if unrealistic words are present. Should be up to OP to decide what fits his needs better.

Comment: With the word 'ping' happen the same and it isn't unrealistic word  ... I think that you only change word_b.split() instead of word_b (in if) and it will be right.

Comment: You said "you may get 100% match in things like "asdf" and "as you did first", as it contains all characters, even though they are completely different things" .... and that is wrong, If you look my code, I check complete word but the similiraty value uses size the word.

Comment: I said I "suspect" that may happen. Your approach is also valid like I said, but its up to OP to see what fits his needs better. I will leave the subject here, as comments are not for extended discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieved with Levenshtein distancing combined with substring matching. What you can do is split a sentence into smaller words (using spaces as a separator), then run the Levenshtein matching algorithm to match individual words with your search string. Something like:

```
def similar_word(string, substring):
    threshold=2

    def levenshtein_distance(s1, s2):
        m, n = len(s1), len(s2)
        dp = [[0] * (n + 1) for _ in range(m + 1)]

        for i in range(m + 1):
            for j in range(n + 1):
                if i == 0: dp[i][j] = j
                elif j == 0: dp[i][j] = i
                elif s1[i - 1] == s2[j - 1]: dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j - 1]
                else: dp[i][j] = 1 + min(dp[i - 1][j], dp[i][j - 1], dp[i - 1][j - 1])
        return dp[m][n]

    for i in range(len(string) - len(substring) + 1):
        distance = levenshtein_distance(string[i:i + len(substring)], substring)
        if distance <= threshold: return True
    
    return False
```

https://gist.github.com/4f77616973/66a784c4c5921359299d603419a8f01b

Since you want the score, you can tweak the above code to return the distance instead of `True`/`False`.

Hope that helps! :)