# How to cluster Named Entity using StanfordNER using python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

Stanford NER provides it NER jars to detect POS tags and NERs. But I am facing one issue with one of the sentences when trying to parse. The sentence is as follows:

```
Joseph E. Seagram & Sons, INC said on Thursday that it is merging its two United States based wine companies
```

Below is my code

```
st = StanfordNERTagger('./stanford- ner/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz',
                       './stanford-ner/stanford-ner.jar',
                       encoding='utf-8')
ne_in_sent = []
with open("./CCAT/2551newsML.txt") as fd:
    lines = fd.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
        tokenized_text = word_tokenize(line)
        classified_text = st.tag(tokenized_text)
        ne_tree = stanfordNE2tree(classified_text)
        for subtree in ne_tree:
            # If subtree is a noun chunk, i.e. NE != "O"
            if type(subtree) == Tree:
                ne_label = subtree.label()
                ne_string = " ".join([token for token, pos in subtree.leaves()])
                ne_in_sent.append((ne_string, ne_label))
                print(ne_in_sent)
```

when I parse it I get the following entities as the organization.
(Joseph E. Seagram & Sons, Organization) and (Inc, Organization)

Also for some other texts in the file like

```
TransCo has a very big plane. Transco is moving south.
```

It differentiates the organizations due to capitalization hence I get
2 entities (TransCo, organization) and (Transco, organization).

Is it possible to convert these into one entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Cosine similarity checker to check the similarity

ref: [Calculate cosine similarity given 2 sentence strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173225/calculate-cosine-similarity-given-2-sentence-strings)