# Search Large file for text and write result to file

Tags: python, search, text

I have file one that is 2.4 millions lines (256mb) and file two that is 32 thousand lines (1.5mb).

I need to go through file two line by line and print matching line in file one.

Pseudocode:

```py
open file 1, read
open file 2, read
open results, write

for line2 in file 2:
    for line1 in file 1:
        if line2 in line1:
            write line1 to results
            stop inner loop
```

My Code:

```py
p = open("file1.txt", "r")
d = open("file2.txt", "r")
o = open("results.txt", "w")

for hash1 in p:
    hash1 = hash1.strip('\n')
    for data in d:
        hash2 = data.split(',')[1].strip('\n')
        if hash1 in hash2:
            o.write(data)

o.close()
d.close()
p.close()
```

I am expecting 32k results.

Comment: Please Follow the code here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15174569/6126313

Comment: Have you tried just running your code? Also, if you're running linux, there's a command called "diff", that may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your file2 is not too large, so it is perfectly well to load it in memory.

- Load file2.txt into a set to speed up search process and remove duplicates;
- Remove empty line from a set;
- Scan file1.txt line-by-line and write found matches in results.txt.

---

```
with open("file2.txt","r") as f:
    lines = set(f.readlines())

lines.discard("\n")

with open("results.txt", "w") as o:
    with open("file1.txt","r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if line in lines:
                o.write(line)
```

If file2 was larger, we could have split it in chunks and repeat the same for every chunk, but in that case it would be harder to compile the results together