# Calculate cosine similarity between sets of document and key words (e.g. "innovate' "fast")

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

I have a set of documents that describe different dimensions of corporate culture. Tokenized examples below:

```
sent1=['innovative','culture','fast','moving','company']
sent2=['manager','micromanage','all','time']
sent3=['slow','response','customer']
```

I've already applied Glove and Gensim w2v to the above documents. I'd like to identify documents that have high cosine similarity score to a sets of word, such as
`Innovation =['innovate','innovative','fast']`

How do I calculate the cosine similarities between each document (e.g. sent1, sent2) and `Innovation` using Gensim?

Ideal Output:

```
       innovation
sent1  0.98
sent2  0.45
sent3  -0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods when it comes to "cosine similarity between sets of documents". You can read some of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173225/calculate-cosine-similarity-given-2-sentence-strings).

But if you want to calculate the CS between just two words, you can do this (were `a` and `b` are your vectors):

```
from numpy import dot
from numpy.linalg import norm

cos_sim = dot(a, b)/(norm(a)*norm(b))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to calculate the similarity between two sentences. (e.g. sent1 and the list of "innovative" words0

Comment: so your answer is on the link. @Yvonne