# Term document matrix and cosine similarity in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, term-document-matrix

I have following situation that I want to address using `Python` (preferably using `numpy` and `scipy`):

1. Collection of documents that I want to convert to a sparse term document matrix.
2. Extract sparse vector representation of each document (i.e. a row in the matrix) and find out top 10 similary documents using cosine similarity within certain subset of documents (documents are labelled with categories and I want to find similar documents within the same category).

How do I achieve this in `Python`? I know I can use `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix` to represent documents as sparse vectors and take dot product to find cosine similarity, but how do I convert the entire corpus to a large but sparse term document matrix (so that I can also extract it's rows as `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix` row vectors)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May I recommend you take a look at [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#common-vectorizer-usage)? This is a very well regarded library in the Python community with a very simple a consistent API. They have also implemented a [cosine similarity](http://scikit-learn.org/0.13/modules/metrics.html) metric. This is an example taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897593/similarity-between-two-text-documents) of how you could do it in 3 lines of code:

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

>>> vect = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1)
>>> tfidf = vect.fit_transform(["I'd like an apple",
...                             "An apple a day keeps the doctor away",
...                             "Never compare an apple to an orange",
...                             "I prefer scikit-learn to Orange"])
>>> (tfidf * tfidf.T).A
array([[ 1.        ,  0.25082859,  0.39482963,  0.        ],
       [ 0.25082859,  1.        ,  0.22057609,  0.        ],
       [ 0.39482963,  0.22057609,  1.        ,  0.26264139],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.26264139,  1.        ]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain attributes `T` and `A` in `(tfidf * tfidf.T).A`?

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni, Sure, `.T` gets you the transpose matrix and `.A` converts from sparse to normal dense representation.

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni my tfidf.shape returns (21488, 12602) which ultimately returns MemoryError. Can you tell me the way to handle such large document?

Comment: In this case you would have to use a [Hashing Vectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#feature-hashing) or use more RAM. If it is too much RAM for a computer then I recommend you use Apache Spark for a distributed(several PCs) calculation.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to this question

[Python: tf-idf-cosine: to find document similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118720/python-tf-idf-cosine-to-find-document-similarity/18914884#18914884)

I have answered the question in which you can find the cosine similarity with [scikit](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/stable/) package.