# Boolean retrieval model in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, information-retrieval

I´m trying to create a query-answer system using boolean model in python.

I tried to use nltk but it seems to be that it doesn´t have functions for the boolean model

I have 3 documents, and I'm  expecting to see which ones are more similar w/ a numeric value.

For example doc1 2.987, doc2 0.876 and doc3 2.156 therefore doc1 and doc2 are similar

What I did:

- tokenized document
- removed duplicated words
- removed stopwords

What I have now is a list of unique words for each document (basically nouns, verbs, adverbs and adjectives)

Now what's the next step?

Comment: Why remove duplicated words? Some of the most often repeated words in a document are likely to relate to the subject, and therefore have a large bearing on whether two documents are similar.

Comment: You r right! I thought it was useful to better remove the stopwords.

Comment: @cms_mgr: in a boolean retrieval model, repeated words have no effect.

Comment: @JPP: boolean retrieval models don't give numeric similarity scores, only boolean scores. You can slap on cosine similarity, but you won't have a strictly boolean model anymore.

Comment: @JPP: What have you tried so far? The question in its current form is not suitable for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Removing stopwords can be useful. You can look for term called Cosine-similarity. Basically it can work on machine learning. It can be used to find the similarity between documents. You can look for [Scikit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) which is there in python. If you want to use that its your choice. But here are some tutorials which explains how can you calculate this cosine similarity.

[part-I](http://blog.christianperone.com/?p=1589),[part-II](http://blog.christianperone.com/?p=1747),[part-III](http://blog.christianperone.com/?p=2497)

Also you can look at this question

[Python: tf-idf-cosine: to find document similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118720/python-tf-idf-cosine-to-find-document-similarity/18914884#18914884)

I hope it helps :)