# How to filter out words with low tf-idf in a corpus with gensim?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

I am using `gensim` for some NLP task. I've created a corpus from `dictionary.doc2bow` where `dictionary` is an object of `corpora.Dictionary`. Now I want to filter out the terms with low tf-idf values before running an LDA model. I looked into the [documentation](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/mmcorpus.html) of the corpus class but cannot find a way to access the terms. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: See this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20140678/tf-idf-implementations-in-python

Answer (score 7):

Say your corpus is the following:

```
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in documents]
```

After running TFIDF you can retrieve a list of low value words:

```
tfidf = TfidfModel(corpus, id2word=dictionary)

low_value = 0.2
low_value_words = []
for bow in corpus:
    low_value_words += [id for id, value in tfidf[bow] if value < low_value]
```

Then filter them out of the dictionary before running LDA:

```
dictionary.filter_tokens(bad_ids=low_value_words)
```

Recompute the corpus now that low value words are filtered out:

```
new_corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in documents]
```

Comment: But if one word has a tf-idf above the threshold in all documents and a tf-idf below the threshold in only one document it is removed from all documents.

Comment: how is this different from dictionary.filter_extremes() if we are using tf-idf to filter out tokens?

Answer (score 3):

This is old, but if you wanted to look at in on a per document level do something like this:

```
#same as before
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(doc_list)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in doc_list]
tfidf = models.TfidfModel(corpus, id2word = dictionary)

#filter low value words
low_value = 0.025

for i in range(0, len(corpus)):
    bow = corpus[i]
    low_value_words = [] #reinitialize to be safe. You can skip this.
    low_value_words = [id for id, value in tfidf[bow] if value < low_value]
    new_bow = [b for b in bow if b[0] not in low_value_words]

    #reassign        
    corpus[i] = new_bow
```

Answer (score 3):

This is essentially same as previous answers, but additionally handles words which are missing in tf-idf representation due to 0 score (terms present in all documents). Previous answer did not filter such terms and they still appeared in the final corpus.

```
#Same as before

dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(doc_list)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in doc_list]
tfidf = models.TfidfModel(corpus, id2word = dictionary)


#Filter low value words and also words missing in tfidf models.

low_value = 0.025

for i in range(0, len(corpus)):
    bow = corpus[i]
    low_value_words = [] #reinitialize to be safe. You can skip this.
    tfidf_ids = [id for id, value in tfidf[bow]]
    bow_ids = [id for id, value in bow]
    low_value_words = [id for id, value in tfidf[bow] if value < low_value]
    words_missing_in_tfidf = [id for id in bow_ids if id not in tfidf_ids] # The words with tf-idf socre 0 will be missing

    new_bow = [b for b in bow if b[0] not in low_value_words and b[0] not in words_missing_in_tfidf]  

#reassign        
corpus[i] = new_bow
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a document `tfidf_doc` which generated by gensim's `TfidfModel()` with the corresponding bag of words document `bow_doc`, and you want to filter words that have tfidf value lower then `cut_percent`% of words in this document, you can call `tfidf_filter(tfidf_doc, cut_percent)`, then it will return a cut version of `tfidf_doc`:

```
def tfidf_filter(tfidf_doc, cut_percent):

    sorted_by_tfidf = sorted(tfidf_doc, key=lambda tup: tup[1])
    cut_value = sorted_by_tfidf[int(len(sorted_by_tfidf)*cut_percent)][1]

    #print('before cut:',len(tfidf_doc))

    #print('cut value:', cut_value)
    for i in range(len(tfidf_doc)-1, -1, -1):
        if tfidf_doc[i][1] < cut_value:
            tfidf_doc.pop(i)

    #print('after cut:',len(tfidf_doc))

    return tfidf_doc
```

Then you want to filter the document `bow_doc` by the resulting `tfidf_doc`, jsut call `filter_bow_by_tfidf(bow_doc, tfidf_doc)`, it will return cut version of `bow_doc`:

```
def filter_bow_by_tfidf(bow_doc, tfidf_doc):
    bow_idx = len(bow_doc)-1
    tfidf_idx = len(tfidf_doc)-1

    #print('before :', len(bow_doc))

    while True:
        if bow_idx < 0: break

        if tfidf_idx < 0:
            #print('pop2 :', bow_doc.pop(bow_idx))
            bow_doc.pop(bow_idx)
            bow_idx -= 1
        if bow_doc[bow_idx][0] > tfidf_doc[tfidf_idx][0]:
            #print('pop1 :', bow_doc.pop(bow_idx))
            bow_doc.pop(bow_idx)
            bow_idx -= 1
        if bow_doc[bow_idx][0] == tfidf_doc[tfidf_idx][0]:
            #print('keep :', bow_doc[bow_idx])
            bow_idx -= 1
            tfidf_idx -= 1

    #print('after :', len(bow_doc))

    return bow_doc
```