# Does NLTK have TF-IDF implemented?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tf-idf

There are TF-IDF implementations in `scikit-learn` and `gensim`.

There are simple implementations [Simple implementation of N-Gram, tf-idf and Cosine similarity in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380394/simple-implementation-of-n-gram-tf-idf-and-cosine-similarity-in-python/22577329#22577329)

To avoid reinventing the wheel,

- **Is there really no TF-IDF in NLTK?**
- **Are there sub-packages that we can manipulate to implement TF-IDF in NLTK? If there are how?**

In this blogpost, it says NLTK doesn't have it. **Is that true?** http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/NLTK/tf_idf_with_scikit-learn_NLTK.php

Comment: considering the docs use sklearn I doubt there is.

Comment: conflicting answers, lol

Comment: Hm, I didn't try tf_idf. Moreover, google can't find tf_idf in the name of function. Double fail)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The NLTK TextCollection class has a method for computing the tf-idf of terms. The documentation is [here](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.text.TextCollection), and the source is [here](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/text.html). However, it says "may be slow to load", so using scikit-learn may be preferable.

Comment: From https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/text.py#L566, this looks expensive: `len([True for text in self._texts if term in text])`

Comment: At least, now we find a spot that we should optimize. If that loop becomes a real cheap operation, we might get some hope =)

Answer (score 4):

I guess, there are enough evidences to conclude non-existence of TF-IDF in NLTK:

1. > Unfortunately, calculating tf-idf is not available in NLTK so we'll
   >   use another data analysis library, scikit-learn

   from [COMPSCI 290-01 Spring 2014 lab](http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/spring14/compsci290/assignments/lab02.html)
2. More important, source code contains nothing related to [tfidf](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tfidf&type=Code) (or [tf-idf](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tf-idf&type=Code)). Exceptions are NLTK-contrib, which contains [map-reduce implementation](https://github.com/nltk/nltk_contrib/blob/master/nltk_contrib/hadoop/tf_idf) for TF-IDF.

There are several libs for tf-idf mentioned in [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20140678/tf-idf-implementations-in-python).

Upd: search by [tf idf](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tf%20idf&type=Code) or [tf_idf](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tf_idf&type=Code) lets to find the function already found by @yvespeirsman