# Is it possible to export a trained Tf-Idf Vectorizer?

Tags: python, nltk, tf-idf

I have a trained Tf-Idf vectorizer and I would like to export it, in order to use it in an application. 
The vectorizer would be the base of an Android app and that is the reason, why I don't want to train the vectorizer again.
I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: yes, pickle it =)

Comment: also, i don't think the tf-idf implemented in `nltk` is fast enough for huge datasets, try `scikit-learn` + `nltk` instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570207/does-nltk-have-tf-idf-implemented

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a way to create an APK from scikit-learn using kivy (+buildozer). However, I managed to create one from the nltk package. Since I'm a press a bit for time I would rather go for the nltk, once I figured out how to use the built APKs in Android Studio.