# what is the difference between tfidf vectorizer and tfidf transformer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I know that the formula for `tfidf vectorizer` is

```
Count of word/Total count * log(Number of documents / no.of documents where word is present)
```

I saw there's tfidf transformer in the scikit learn and I just wanted to difference between them. I could't find anything that's helpful.

Comment: Refer the doc [TfidfTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html). It might help you

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar It was confusing a bit. I couldn't understand the formula used. I am hoping someone here might be able to help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) is used on sentences, while 
[TfidfTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html) is used on an existing count matrix, such as one returned by [CountVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)

Comment: So it basically converts the sparse count matrix returned by countvectorizer to tfidf matrix.

Answer (score 6):

Artem's answer pretty much sums up the difference.
To make things clearer here is an example as referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118720/python-tf-idf-cosine-to-find-document-similarity/12128777#12128777).

**TfidfTransformer** can be used as follows:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer


train_set = ["The sky is blue.", "The sun is bright."] 

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
trainVectorizerArray =   vectorizer.fit_transform(article_master['stemmed_content'])

transformer = TfidfTransformer()
res = transformer.fit_transform(trainVectorizerArray)

print ((res.todense()))


## RESULT:  

Fit Vectorizer to train set
[[1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1]]

[[0.70710678 0.         0.70710678 0.        ]
 [0.         0.70710678 0.         0.70710678]]
```

Extraction of count features, TF-IDF normalization and row-wise euclidean normalization can be done in one operation with **TfidfVectorizer**:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
res1 = tfidf.fit_transform(train_set)
print ((res1.todense()))


## RESULT:  

[[0.70710678 0.         0.70710678 0.        ]
 [0.         0.70710678 0.         0.70710678]]
```

Both processes produce a sparse matrix comprising of the same values.
Other useful references would be [tfidfTransformer.fit_transform](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.fit_transform), [countVectoriser_fit_transform](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.fit_transform) and [tfidfVectoriser](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer) .

Answer (score 5):

With Tfidftransformer you will compute word counts using CountVectorizer and then compute the IDF values and only then compute the Tf-idf scores. With Tfidfvectorizer you will do all three steps at once.

I think you should read [this article which sums it up with an example](https://kavita-ganesan.com/tfidftransformer-tfidfvectorizer-usage-differences/).

Answer (score 0):

Both tfidf vectorizer and transformer are same but differ only in ***Normalization*** step.

tfidf transformer perform that extra step called "Normalization" to make all the values within the 0 to 1 range,where as tfidf vectorizer doesnot perform the Normalization step.

For Normalizing purpose tfidf transformer uses the "Norm" like Euclidean Norm(L2).

Example:

tf-idf = [4,0.2,0]

Above vector was obtained after calculated the term-frequency(tf) and inverse document frequency(idf).

**NOTE:The above vector is obtained in tfidf vectorizer also.but tfidf vectorizer stop process after getting the above vector**

Here we are using the Euclidean Norm to do the Normalization.

[Formula for Euclidean Norm to do Normalization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgJAc.png)

```
  =      [4,0.2,0]
    ---------------------
    sqrt(4^2 + 0.2^2 + 0)

  =[1,0.05,0]
```

So the above vector is the normalized vector which is computed by the tfidf transformer.