# Attribute error while using scikit-learn

Tags: python, nltk, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I am trying to find similar questions using scikit using cosine similarity. I was trying this sample code available on the internet. [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118720/python-tf-idf-cosine-to-find-document-similarity) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911469/tfidf-for-search-queries)

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as LA

train_set = ["The sky is blue.", "The sun is bright."]
test_set = ["The sun in the sky is bright."]
stopWords = stopwords.words('english')

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words = stopWords)
transformer = TfidfTransformer()

trainVectorizerArray = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_set).toarray()
trainVectorizerArray = vectorizer.
testVectorizerArray = vectorizer.transform(test_set).toarray()
print 'Fit Vectorizer to train set', trainVectorizerArray
print 'Transform Vectorizer to test set', testVectorizerArray
cx = lambda a, b : round(np.inner(a, b)/(LA.norm(a)*LA.norm(b)), 3)

for vector in trainVectorizerArray:
    print vector
    for testV in testVectorizerArray:
        print testV
        cosine = cx(vector, testV)
        print cosine

transformer.fit(trainVectorizerArray)
print transformer.transform(trainVectorizerArray).toarray()

transformer.fit(testVectorizerArray)
tfidf = transformer.transform(testVectorizerArray)
print tfidf.todense()
```

I always get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Animesh\Desktop\NLP\ngrams2.py", line 14, in <module>
trainVectorizerArray = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_set).toarray()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scikit_learn-0.13.1-py2.7-win32.egg\sklearn  \feature_extraction\text.py", line 740, in fit_transform
raise ValueError("empty vocabulary; training set may have"
ValueError: empty vocabulary; training set may have contained only stop words or min_df  (resp. max_df) may be too high (resp. too low).
```

I even checked the code available on [this link](http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/wordpress/?p=1589). There I got error `AttributeError: 'CountVectorizer' object has no attribute 'vocabulary'`.

How to solve this issue ?

I am using Python 2.7.3 on Windows 7 32 Bit and scikit_learn 0.13.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since I'm running the development (pre-0.14) version, where the `feature_extraction.text` module got overhauled, I don't get the same error message. But I suspect you can solve this issue with:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words=stopWords, min_df=1)
```

The `min_df` parameter causes `CountVectorizer` to throw away any term that occurs in too few documents (because it won't have any predictive value). By default, it's set to 2, which means all your terms get thrown away, so you get an empty vocabulary.

Comment: Oh! That solved the issue.. But could you tell me whats with the vocabulary function... why is it giving an attribute error when I try to use this function

Comment: @AnimeshPandey: it's right there in the error message: "empty vocabulary; training set may have contained only stop words or min_df (resp. max_df) may be too high (resp. too low)." As I explained, the default setting `min_df=2` is too low because you only have two documents. (Mind you, tf-idf doesn't work properly with so few documents either.)

Comment: `vocabulary_` with a trailing `_` is extracted when calling the fit method (unless provided as a constructor parameters by the user). See the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction).