# Best match for input query from a set of documents

Tags: python, tf-idf

I have 8 documents and I ran `TF-IDF` on it to get an array. I don't understand how I find out which is the best document match for a given input query?

```
all_documents = [doc1, doc2, ...., doc7]
sklearn_tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(norm='l2',min_df=0, use_idf=True, smooth_idf=False, sublinear_tf=True, tokenizer=tokenize)
sklearn_representation = sklearn_tfidf.fit_transform(all_documents).toarray()
```

Comment: By the best document, do you mean the closest document to input query? You have to fit `TfidfVectorizer` to input query and then find the distance to vector from the 7 documents that you have (this can be cosine distance/ euclidean distance).

Comment: @titipat thanks for the approach. But as I understand, to find any of the mentioned distance the length of vectors should be same. How will I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Transform the input to `tf-idf` format using `TfidfVectorizer`. You can then use a distance metric (cosine, euclidean, manhattan, ...) to calculate the document that is closest to your input.

Each of the documents should use the same vocabulary. I assume that your 8 document vectors have the same length? The `sklearn_tfidf` object that you created has an attribute `vocabulary_` that contains all words that are used in the vectors. Your input query should be reduced to only containing those words.

**Example**

```
Document1: dogs are cute
Document2: cats are awful
```

Leads to a vocabulary of `[dogs, cats, are, cute, awful]`. A query containing other words than these 5 cannot be used. For example if your query is `cute animals`, the `animals` has no meaning, because it cannot be found in one of the documents. The query thus reduces to following vector: `[0,0,0,1,0]` since `cute` is the only word that can be found in the documents.

Comment: Thanks for the approach. But as I understand, to find any of the mentioned distance the length of vectors should be same. How will I do that?

Comment: Each of the documents should use the same vocabulary. I assume that your 8 document vectors have the same length? The `sklearn_tfidf` object that you created has an attribute `vocabulary_` that contains all words that are used in the vectors. Your input query should be reduced to only containing those words.

Comment: Yes, the length of every vector is 1058. But how do I convert the input string to length of 1058 size vector?

Comment: I tried and can see list of vocabulary with length 1058. Should I build a vector of length of 1's and 0's comparing every word in input query to the  `vocabulary_` or is there a method in scikit learn which I can use directly?

Comment: I think [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911469/tfidf-for-search-queries) can help you out.